# How split a apigw serverless.yml events node?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I try to split a part of my serverless.yml template, **events node**, into multiple sub-files. I have a fairly large lamba api gateway. The “events” node is growing very long, its becoming difficult to manage.

**I CANT split a function or service**, its important that reamin only one api service.
Its possible to divide only “events” node of serverless template into sub several files, for example for each event of my api service (sections, roles, etc), such as:

sections-events.sls.yml, roles-events.sls.yml, and so on?

Ive tried more solutions but none worked..

This is my original serverless.yml template.
[image]

This is one of the tests I've done using template variables but it doesn't work ..
[image]

Looking at the sls documentation, I thought it was possible to structure the template as follows:

```
functions:
  graphql:
   handler: src/index.handler
   ...
   events:
     ${file(./sections-events.serverless.yml):events}
     ${file(./roles-events.serverless.yml):events}
```

but the template validator returns an error as the events node must be an array and this syntax is not possible.

TEST 1:
[image]
TEST 2:
[image]

I hope someone can help me find a possible path, even though im convinced that isn't feasible!

Thanks a lot to the whole community!

Good Job.

Comment: Ignore the errors.

Comment: In both cases (test1 and test2) the lambda function doest recognize the routes described in the sls file, returns: configuration warning at 'functions.graphql.events [0]': should be object!

Comment: Note: i user serverless-offline plugin to run in localhost